# Prism Singleton Settings

Tags: design-patterns, prism, unity-container

Want to implement a pattern-based approach for having a Settings Class
which could be used in every module.

**I have :**

1. Business Objects in an assembly (Doesn't Referenced anything)
2. Common Assembly (Infrastructure)
3. Services Module- Implemented IModule (In the defining phase)

**A Settings Class :**

```
[Serializable]
public class  Settings
{
    public string DefaultStoreLocation
    { get; set; }
...
}
```

It should be instantiated somewhere in the application's startup.
and the application will work with that singleton instance during it's life-cycle.
e.g here : **ApplicationSettings**

```
Settings ApplicationSettings = new Settings();
```

*Which where should I place this Settings File ?*

*and How to set the strategy for that ?*

---

**Doubts :**

1. Should use ContainerControlledlifetimeManager while registering the Type in each module ?
   (Don't know exactly how and when).
2. Should it be placed in a simple assembly or it could be better if I place it in a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> want to implement a pattern-based approach

Don't try to build a GOF-complete application. Patterns are something that evolves from your code. Don't force your code to look like a pattern just because you think its cool.

`Settings` sound like something that belongs to your infrastructure. Put it there. The infrastructure assembly can be referenced from any module.

Create and populate the settings inside your bootstrapper. You can also register them with Unity there.

```cs
var settings = new Settings { Foo = 1, Bar = "abc" };
container.RegisterInstance(settings);
```

If your module has a constructor that accepts a parameter of Type `Settings` the container will inject the settings into the modules when they are created.

Comment: +1, For the info, still have some minor questions regarding this. Yes, I've put that in the infrastructure, I instantiated the Settings in the constructor of my Services Module. I would set the Dependency of every other module to the services module. Thought that way could be a good structure and other modules such as the DomainModule could use the ApplicationSettings. Am I in the right direction. That was what I did. And about your strategy which you said place it in the bootstrapper, how could other modules access this "ApplicationSettings". Again thanks for your help

Comment: please answer this: I registered the ApplicationSettings, Made the Constructor of a sample module accept the type and assigned that there. I'm not a unity expert, Does it been passed automatically to the modules constructor ?

Comment: Depending on how your modules are registered with the ModuleCatalog the Container is Used to instantiate them. There is a method related to the catalog in the bootstrapper. If you only Register module types and Not instances it should Work. Sorry for the weird casing. My phone tries to help

Comment: Thanks, I got what I needed and it works, On any change if I needed further help or questions will open new questions.